# SQL Server 2008: delete duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I have duplicate rows in my table, how can I delete them based on a single column's value?

Eg

```
uniqueid, col2, col3 ...
1, john, simpson
2, sally, roberts
1, johnny, simpson

delete any duplicate uniqueIds
to get 

1, John, Simpson
2, Sally, Roberts
```

Comment: Which would you keep? johnny or john?

Comment: I dont mind which i keep.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can `DELETE` from a cte:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY uniqueid ORDER BY col2)'RowRank'
             FROM Table)
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE RowRank > 1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns a number to each row.  `PARTITION BY` is used to start the numbering over for each item in that group, in this case each value of `uniqueid` will start numbering at 1 and go up from there.  `ORDER BY` determines which order the numbers go in.  Since each `uniqueid` gets numbered starting at 1, any record with a `ROW_NUMBER()` greater than 1 has a duplicate `uniqueid`

To get an understanding of how the `ROW_NUMBER()` function works, just try it out:

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY uniqueid ORDER BY col2)'RowRank'
FROM Table
ORDER BY uniqueid
```

You can adjust the logic of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to adjust which record you'll keep or remove.

For instance, perhaps you'd like to do this in multiple steps, first deleting records with the same last name but different first names, you could add last name to the `PARTITION BY`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY uniqueid, col3 ORDER BY col2)'RowRank'
             FROM Table)
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE RowRank > 1
```

Comment: This is the cleanest method.

Comment: Can you explain what 'SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, ORDER BY col2)'RowRank'FROM Table' does?

Comment: Sure thing, updated the answer to include a description of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: By Id do you mean UniqueId - PARTITION BY ID. Also why Orderby Col2 - i dont care if col2 is duplicating, i want to remove duplicates of UniqueId not caring which is left behind

Comment: Yeah, ID = UniqueId in your case.  The `ORDER BY` could just as well be `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` to make it arbitrary. Again, the `PARTITION BY` defines the field that will be numbered from 1-n, the `ORDER BY` is required in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, so in effect it determines which duplicate gets deleted and which doesn't.

Comment: Is there a way to change this to return the rows that were deleted?

Comment: @NicholasJDininno  There are two options, you can change the `DELETE` to a `SELECT` to view all records that will be affected by the `DELETE`. You can also use the `OUTPUT` clause to output deleted rows to another table:  `DELETE FROM cte 
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO #Deleted
WHERE RowRank > 1`

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a row id that *is* assigned by the DB upon insertion and is actually unique. I'll call this rowId in my example.

```
rowId |uniqueid |col2  |col3
----- |-------- |----  |----
1      10        john   simpson
2      20        sally  roberts
3      10        johnny simpson
```

You can remove duplicates by grouping on the thing that is supposed to be unique (whether it be one column or many), then you grab a rowId from each group, and delete everything else besides those rowIds. In the inner query, everything in the table will have a rowId except for the duplicate rows.

```
select * 
--DELETE 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE rowId NOT IN 
(SELECT MIN(rowId) 
 FROM MyTable 
 GROUP BY uniqueid);
```

You could also use MAX instead of MIN with similar results.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @du TABLE (
    id INT,  
    Name VARCHAR(4)
)

INSERT INTO @du VALUES(1,'john')
INSERT INTO @du VALUES(2,'jane')
INSERT INTO @du VALUES(1,'john')

;WITH dup (id,dp)
AS
(SELECT id
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Name) AS dp
FROM @du)
DELETE FROM dup
WHERE dp > 1

SELECT *
FROM @du
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple magic to remove duplicates

```
select * into NewTable from ExistingTable
union
select * from ExistingTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM table WHERE uniqueid='1' AND col2='john'`
Or you change `col2='john'` to `col2='johnny'`. Depends on which record you want to delete.

How did you end up with two same "unique" IDs in the first place?

Comment: This only answers the very specific example that the OP gave, as it was only an example they are presumably hoping for a more generic solution

Comment: This is hard coded for the example no? Im still trying to figure out how i ended up with the dupes tbh.

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways for deleting the duplicate records some of them are below...........

**Different ways to delete Duplicate records**

Using Row_Number() function and CTE

```
  with CTE(DuplicateCount) as  ( SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER
(PARTITION by UniqueId order by UniqueId ) as DuplicateCount from
Table1 ) Delete from CTE where DuplicateCount > 1

  .Without using CTE*

Delete DuplicateCount from ( Select Row_Number() over(Partition by
UniqueId order by UniqueId) as Dup from Table1 ) DuplicateCount 
where DuplicateCount.Dup > 1

 .Without using row_Number() and CTE

Delete from Subject where RowId not in(select Min(RowId ) from
Subject group by UniqueId)
```