# How to delete the duplicate based on date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I have several cust_id duplicates. I would like to keep the row where prendate_next is nearest to the current date and delete the rest of the duplicates. Please help me how. I am new to this

```
cust_id     prendate_next
1000105737  2014-11-30 00:00:00.000
1000105836  2014-11-20 00:00:00.000
1000143646  2014-11-10 00:00:00.000
1000143646  2015-03-09 00:00:00.000
1000179487  2014-12-05 00:00:00.000
1000182253  2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
1000192740  2014-10-02 00:00:00.000
1000192740  2015-01-10 00:00:00.000
1000199419  2015-09-30 00:00:00.000
1000170578  2014-12-26 00:00:00.000
1000188890  2015-06-23 00:00:00.000
1000189075  2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
1000189075  2015-03-01 00:00:00.000
1000189144  2015-04-04 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Do you have another unique id in this table?

Comment: duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256201/sql-server-2008-delete-duplicate-rows

Comment: yes i do have an onther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT      cust_id, prendate_next,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,prendate_next,GETDATE()))) AS RowNumber
    FROM        MyTable
)

DELETE MyTable
    FROM        MyTable
    INNER JOIN  cte         ON MyTable.cust_id = cte.cust_id
                            AND MyTable.prendate_next = cte.prendate_next
    WHERE       cte.RowNumber != 1
```

`ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,prendate_next,GETDATE()))` counts how many days `prendate_next` is from today.